# python3のfor文でDB接続のエラーが出ても、その後のループ処理を続けたい

Tags: python, python3, postgresql

Python3とPostgreSQLを利用して、WEBシステムを開発しています。

下記のように、リストに入っている値をfor文を使って、データベースに登録するためのコードを作成しました。

登録するテーブルのカラムはInteger型のため、str型のデータが含まれる場合は、try文でexcept処理して、次のfor文のループさせたいのですが、except処理される時に、for文の処理がとまってしまいます。

カラムの型に合わないデータは、except処理をして、さらにその後のfor文の動きを続けるには、どのようなコードにすれば良いのか、ご存じの方おりましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

●サンプルコード1

```
import psycopg2


sql_check1 = false
sql_check2 = []

conText = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sample user=user password=password"

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conText)
    cur = connection.cursor()
except:
    sql_check1 = True

#① int,int,str,intのリストを作成
data_list[10,20,'error_data',30]

for i in range(len(data_list)):

    try:
        #② Integer型のdataカラムにdata_listの値を保存したい
        sql = "INSERT INTO sample_table(data) VALUES(%s);"
        values = (data_list[i])
        cur.execute(sql, values)

        connection.commit()

    except:
        #③for文3回目（data_list[2]）の時にexceptの対象となる
        sql_check2.append(data_list[i])
        #④ここでfor文が止まってしまい、4回目のループに行かない
```

開発環境
Python: 3.7.5
PostgreSQL: 12.1

---

**追記**
●サンプルコード2

```
import psycopg2

sql_check1 = false
sql_check2 = []
cast_check = false  # 追記

conText = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sample user=user password=password"

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conText)
    cur = connection.cursor()
except:
    sql_check1 = True

# ① int,int,str,intのリストを作成
data_list[10, 20, 'error_data', 30]

for i in range(len(data_list)):

    # 追記スタート
    try:
        int(data_list[i])
    except:
        cast_check = True
　　　# 追記終了

    try:
        # ② Integer型のdataカラムにdata_listの値を保存したい
        sql = "INSERT INTO sample_table(data) VALUES(%s);"
        values = (data_list[i])
        cur.execute(sql, values)

        connection.commit()

    except:
        # ③for文3回目（data_list[2]）の時にexceptの対象となる
        sql_check2.append(data_list[i])
        # ④ここでfor文が止まってしまい、4回目のループに行かない
```

Comment: [こちらの回答](https://teratail.com/questions/141409#reply-213753)が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: その前に型を調べてInteger以外は呼ばないようにすれば良いのでは？ [【Python】変数の型を調べる方法(type)と型を判定する方法(isinstance)](https://neko-py.com/python-type-inspect) まあエラーは他の理由でも起こるでしょうから対策は必要でしょうけれど。

Comment: @ metropolisさんありがとうございます。紹介していただいたサイト拝見しました。私のコードにcontinueがない事が、次のループに行かない一つの理由と思います。ただ、質問文に追記したように、strのデータをint型にキャストする所にtry,except処理をすると、continueを加えなくても、次のコードへと進みます。サンプルコード中の”# ③for文3回目（data_list[2]）の時にexceptの対象となる”の部分でfor文が止まるのは、データベースの接続が切れてしまった事も関係あるのでしょうか？continueを加える場合は、データベースの接続の処理を再度行う必要はありますでしょうか？

Comment: @ kunifさんありがとうございます。Integer以外は呼ばないようにする方法も良いですね。今回はtry.exceptでexceptを使う内容での開発にトライしたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `data_list` が作れていません。`data_list` は変数ですよね? 代入してください。
- `values` はタプルです。例えば `(1,2,3)` はタプルです。要素が一つの場合には `(1)` としたいところですが、これだと式をまとめるただの括弧と区別が付かないので `(1,)` と書きます。同様に、`(data_list[i],)` とします。

たぶん、ここまでは質問にコードをコピペする時に間違ったのでしょう。重要なのはここからで、for は途中で止まってはいません。

- 例外が本当に意図した時にだけ起きているかを確認するため、例外は受け取って出力してみるのが良いでしょう。
- SQL の実行に失敗すると、トランザクションを継続することはできません。3番目と4番目は、間にトランザクションを分ける処理がないので、一つのトランザクションとなっています。従って、3番目で失敗すると、4番目は必ず失敗します。

1番目2番めで commit してトランザクションをそこで終了させるなら、3番目が失敗した時には rollback でトランザクションを終了させるのが良いでしょう。そうすれば、4番目の SQL が実行できます。(といったことが、例外を出力してみるとわかります)。

結果として、コードは以下のようになります。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import psycopg2

sql_check1 = False
sql_check2 = []

conText = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sample user=user password=password"

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(conText)
    cur = connection.cursor()
except:
    sql_check1 = True

# ① int,int,str,intのリストを作成
data_list = [10, 20, 'error_data', 30]

for i in range(len(data_list)):

    try:
        # ② Integer型のdataカラムにdata_listの値を保存したい
        sql = "INSERT INTO sample_table(data) VALUES(%s);"
        values = (data_list[i],)
        cur.execute(sql, values)

        connection.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # ③for文3回目（data_list[2]）の時にexceptの対象となる
        sql_check2.append(data_list[i])
        # ④ここでfor文が止まってしまい、4回目のループに行かない
        connection.rollback()
```

Comment: @masmさん、大変ご丁寧な回答いただきありがとうございます。非常に参考になりました。今まではcontinueがデータベースへの処理を続けるために必要なものとばかり思っていましたので、rollbackで対応するというに意識がいっておりませんでした。今回教えていただいた知識を活用して今後の開発を行っていこうと思います。